# Combining named arguments and variadic arguments

Tags: php

There is a function:

```
function foo(string $domain, string $streamId, string $app = 'live', TypeEnum ...$type) {}
```

and `TypeEnum`:

```
enum TypeEnum: string {
    case Flv = 'flv';
    case M3u8 = 'm3u8';
    case Rtmp = 'rtmp';
}
```

When I call function `foo`, I know I can do it with the following, to pass two values to the variable-length `...$type` argument:

```
foo('domain', 'stream id', 'live', TypeEnum::Flv, TypeEnum::M3u8);
```

The $app has default value, so I want to skip it using named parameters; but how can I pass the arguments to `$type`?

```
// wrong
foo('domain', 'stream id',  type: TypeEnum::Flv, TypeEnum::M3u8);
// wrong
foo('domain', 'stream id',  type: [TypeEnum::Flv, TypeEnum::M3u8]);
// wrong
foo('domain', 'stream id',  type: TypeEnum::Flv, type: TypeEnum::M3u8);
```

I tried the above and got an error for all of them. I didn't find any relevant examples in PHP's documentation.